Son enters a competition for opening and closing doors
I watched it around the turn of the millennium and it was fairly new then. Classed as world cinema, possibly eastern European, black humour/drama, about a young boy entered into a door opening and closing completion (forced by his father? Maybe).
Film was about (I think) hardships of growing up in a poor family/area. The film was mainly from the boys (maybe 10-12 yrs old) point of view, and his journey. (falling for a girl for the first time).
The climax of the film was the competition (at a school or community centre), on a stage where he had to either open the door x times over a.period of time or had to constantly open and close the door over a set time period. (this seemed to be the highpoint in the community calender).
There was no fantasy, or sci fi element to the film.
I can't remember much more other than that I enjoyed it and would like to revisit it. (I watched it on VHS bought at HMV, in UK.)
I've tried various searches to no success. Can you tell me the name of this movie?

Sounds like the Belgian comedy Les convoyeurs attendent (AKA The Carriers Are Waiting) From 1999. From an online recap:

Roger is a photographer for a local newspaper, a husband and father of two, the teenaged Micheland and his little sister Luisa. He is disappointed with family life and wants something more. He gets an opportunity to enter a competition for breaking records where the main prize is a new car. He decides to train his son to break the record for opening and closing doors in twenty-four hours and finds him a coach.

